# How can I access elements of a frame without a frame tag using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

The concept of frames is being used on a website I am tasked with testing. However, the frames do not use frame tags, one is for example a div that is filled by GET/POST. Selenium cannot access the element inside of the frame (ElementNotVisibleException) because it must first switch to the frame. But, I can't switch to the frame because it is not technically a frame in Selenium's eyes. How can I access the content of the frame without manipulating the DOM? (The point of testing is that we test what is there as an end user and don't change it). So, I cannot use JavaScript executor. I have tried using action building to click elements/move to the element, but it returns errors.

EDIT:

Here is the basic form of the html I'm trying to access. I cannot use selenium to access any elements inside `el1`. I need to select an option for `el6`.

```
<div id="el1" style="width: 960px; height: 230px; margin-bottom: 6px;">
     <div style="width: 955px;padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px;">
          <span>Text Here</span>
          <form id="el2" action="pageName.jsp?action=blah" method="POST" style="height: 300px;" name="el2">
               <div id="el3" style="width: 600px; margin: 20px 0px 0px 60px;">
                    <div id="el4" style="height: 20px;">
                         <div id="el5" style="height: 20px; padding-left: 40px;">
                              <div style="width: 400px;">
                                   <span style="font-weight: bold;">More Text Here</span>
                              </div>
                              <div style="width: 400px;">
                                   <select id="el6" onchange="javascriptfunction(this)" name="el6" style="width: 400px;">
                                        <option selected="selected" value="">A Select Box Option</option>
                                        <option value="NumberHere">More Options Populated By JSP</option>
                                   </select>
                              </div>
                         </div>                
                    </div>
               </div>
           <!--Some Unnecessary content here-->
          </form>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is style calculation for `el6`. I have tried manually adjusting height with WebDriver in attempt to get rid of ElementNotVisibleException. This did not work.

```
font-family MS Shell Dlg
body    Helvetica,​Arial,​Sans-Serif    
div Arial,​Helvetica,​Geneva,​sans-serif    
body    Arial,​Helvetica,​Geneva,​sans-serif    
font-size   13.3333px
div 14px    
body    13px    
color   rgb(0,​ 0,​ 0)
     #container #333    
text-align  start
     #wrapper   left    
     .bodyStyle center  
width   400px
margin-top  0px
margin-right    0px
margin-bottom   0px
margin-left 0px
padding-top 0px
padding-right   0px
padding-bottom  0px
padding-left    0px
```

Comment: If it is technically no `<iframe>`, why do you want to switch to it? It should be possible to access it using Xpath or Css selector (although it is hard to tell without page code). If it is not visible, that might be due to some unfinished GET request. in that case, try to wait for it to finsh.

Comment: It is either not a wait issue, or I am not waiting correctly. I have tried many forms of waits, but all timeout or do not fix the problem.

Comment: The element in the html has `action="page.jsp?action=foo"` and `method="POST"`. So my guess is that the POST action is happening somewhat continuously, preventing selenium from "seeing" the elements. I may be completely wrong though.

Comment: Can you please share the HTML code of the elements you want to access ?

Comment: I will post an edit with basic layout and inherited/calculated properties of an element I'm trying to access, but I can't post a majority of it.

Comment: same situation here also,without frame how to identify elements

Answer (score 0):

why can't you switch to any available iframe without specifying the ID or name.
you can do this just switch to iframe..

try this

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe")));
```

Comment: This answer missed the point of the question entirely.... There are no iframes in the page. I stated this above.

Comment: I agree.. but if it's an invisible iframe.. it has all the chances of switching to iframe..

Comment: It's not invisible. The tag `iframe` does not exist at all in the html. I said the concept of frames is being used. `iframe` tags are not used, therefore Selenium cannot use `driver.switchTo().frame()`

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are getting ElementNotVisibleException,it means element is invisible at that time.You can use explicit wait to achieve this :

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,<Time>);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("el6"))); 

First,you calculate time which is taken by element to visible and replace with <Time>.

For more detail,you can [see][1].


  [1]: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp
```

Comment: You have to figure out when it can be make visible and how much time is required to visible the element.Otherwise you will get times out exception.

Comment: I have let it sit for over a minute. I don't think it would take more than a minute for it to appear as visible if it was going to change. What would you suggest is a suitable amount of time to wait? How are you "calculating" time for it to be visible? I can see the element rendered on the screen, but selenium cannot recognize it. It is not hidden/display:none/height: 0px.